# Select a cell value from a range based on criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, worksheet-function

I'm trying to figure out a sleeker method for determining the value of a cell based on criteria defined in a given range. To put it bluntly, I have a column for standard viscosity, standard temperature, and measured temperature. I'm needing to create a fourth column that will select the standard viscosity based on the measured temperature. For example, if measured temperature is greater than or equal to 0<sup>o</sup>C and less than 1<sup>o</sup>C: return standard viscosity for 0<sup>o</sup>C.

My issue is that I have a large range and find it to tedious to create a custom expression for each range. I've created a nightmarish function that was composed of IF(AND()) statements but find this exhausting, especially if I try to create an expression for a 0-200<sup>o</sup>C scale in single digit increments.

Here is a sample of a code that works but is quite cumbersome:

```
=IF(AND(G8>=$C$7,G8<$C$8),$D$7,0)+IF(AND(G8>=$C$8,G8<$C$9),$D$8,0)+....
```

or

```
=IF(AND(measured temp>=0,measured temp<1),$D$7,0)+IF(AND(measured temp>=1,measured temp<2),$D$8,0)
```

How could I approach this in a sleeker manner?

Comment: Is the column Standard temperature sorted? In ascending order?

Comment: Yes, the column is sorted in ascending order. 0,1,2,5,9...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by the VLOOKUP function.

```
=VLOOKUP(G8;$C$7:$D$...;2;TRUE)
```

Replace the three dots with the index of the last row of your table.

The first argument of VLOOKUP is the value to search for; the second argument is the range whose first column is to be searched for the value; the third argument is the index of the column containing the values to return (within the range, so 2 means the second column within the range, which is D in your case); TRUE means that you do not want to search for an exact match, but that the column to be search is an ordered list of values defining intervals.

Edit:

With MATCH and OFFSET (guessed, not tried), if column with result values is left relative to column of criterion values:

```
=OFFSET($C$7;...;MATCH(G8;$C$7:$C$...;1) - 1)
```

Replace the first three dots with the position of the result column, relative to column C (so 1 if it's column D, and -1 if it's column B), and the second three dots with the index of the last row of your range, as above.

Edit2:

INDEX instead of OFFSET is even better, se pnuts's answer and the comment below:

```
=INDEX($D7:$D...;MATCH(G8;$C$7:$C$...;1))
```

Comment: I've tried that too. Perhaps a misapplication of it?  It only works if the data to compare to is in the left hand column. My issue is that the data to pull from can be to the right or left with other columns in between.

Comment: It would have been very kind to mention that in the question. You probably can achieve what you want by MATCH together with INDIRECT and/or OFFSET.

Comment: Awesome! That worked perfectly! I was not having it index properly the first time around! Thanks!

Comment: @NAC I would prefer the formula of pnuts. Both OFFSET and INDIRECT are volatile functions and will recalculate every single time something changes in your workbook even if it is unrelated to your data (can be really cumbersome and slow down your computer). INDEX on the other hand would re-evaluate only when your data changes.

Comment: Yes, probably INDEX is the better choice.

Answer (score 2):

If your measured temperature is say in F2 and your data table is A:C please try:

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(F2,C:C))
```